# C - Ignore trailing comments when reading text file

Tags: c, parsing

I have a text file with the following format:

```
1 // Comment
2 // Comment
3 
4 // Comment
5
6 // Comment
7 // Comment
8 // Comment
9 
etc.....
```

I am using C to try and parse out the numbers, while ignoring the comments completely, and read the integers into an array. The array has a predetermined size, so the amount of numbers in the text file won't exceed that. I have just started learning C, and I have tried using fgets() and strtok() with the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file;
    char buf[1000];

    if (argc == 2)
        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect number of arguments.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!file)
        return 1;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file) != NULL)

        printf("%s\n", strtok(buf, "//"));


    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

I haven't tried to put the integers into an array yet, as I am still just trying to isolate the numbers somehow. This is my output:

```
1 
2 
3 

4 
5

6 
7 
8 
9
```

So, I am having trouble dealing with white space following the number. For all I know, there is probably a much simpler way to accomplish this, but this is what I have after a couple of hours of messing around with it. How can I account for this space, or, is there a better way to parse only the integers out of this file and into an array?

Comment: Is the format always "number[space][optional comment]"?

Comment: Did you **read the documentation** of [strtok(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html); you are using it incorrectly! Also, compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes, the format will always be number[space][optional comment]

Comment: What exactly is the format? Is it: `digits [non-digit-non-newline non-newlines] newline` ? Is that space optional too?

Comment: @Deduplicator There will be a digit first followed by 3 to 4 spaces, depending on if it's a single or double-digit number. Then followed by an optional comment a single space after the comment and the comment itself of varying length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fgets() leaves the newline (\n) character on the line if one exists.  So the lines with comments are:
     ## // Comment\n
The lines without comments are:
     ##\n

When you call strtok(), it splits the line into tokens based on the separator, in your case "//".  So the lines with comments return "## " and " Comment\n", and the lines without comments return just "##\n".  So when you print them, the lines without comments end up with two linefeeds.

A simple way to retrieve your number in this format is atoi(buf).  Since atoi() skips leading whitespace, parses an option leading + or - sign, and then parses all digits, in the case of both comment lines and no comment lines it will return the integer value of the number.

Comment: I didn't notice this about my .txt file before, but some lines are just blank, and when using aoti(), these blank lines are read in as zeroes. I am having trouble putting valid 0's into my array and ignoring blank lines (not reading them into the array as 0's).

Comment: Well, I figured out how to ignore blank lines by checking for '\n', but now I am attempting to deal with comments ('//' type) that are spaced over 6 spaces or so.

Comment: My understanding is that the first file is your input, and has no blank lines, and the second file is your output after using strtok() to try to get the number.  What I was suggesting was that you not use strtok(), but instead use atoi().  If you have blank lines in that file, then you will indeed need to check for buf[0] == '\n'

Comment: I have accounted for the blank lines by using buf[0] == '\n', but there are also comment lines that do not trail an integer. For example there is a block of lines like the input posted above, followed by a blank line and then a comment line with no integer at the beginning, spaced over about 6 spaces (not tabbed). So the '//' begins after a few space marks. I having trouble accounting for this, and atoi() continues reading this comment line in as a zero.

Comment: atoi() will return a 0 unless it finds digits.  Now, you're saying that the input lines you have are: "No spaces, digits, spaces, and comment", "No spaces and digits", and "Spaces and comments", right?  Is that all of the line formats in the input file?  Are you only supposed to count the lines that have digits?  If the answer to all 3 questions is true, then add 'if( !isdigit(buf[0]) { continue }' to skip the lines without numbers at the start, and for the rest call atoi(buf) and add the results to your list.

Comment: that solved my problem. Still have a lot to learn about parsing text with C.

Answer (score 2):

As each line begins with a number, and the rest of the line shall be ignored, do this:

```
int number;
while(1 == fscanf(file, "%d%*[^\n]\n", &number)) {
    // Work with number here
}
```

The format is:

- `%d`: a signed decimal number fitting into an `int`
- `%*[^\n]`: An unrestricted number of characters which are not newline, won't be assigned due to `*`
- `\n`: The newline terminating the line

`fscanf` returns the number of outputs assigned, and will stop if something cannot be matched.

Comment: Note that `"%d%*[^\n]\n"` will not consume a `'\n'` directly following a number.  The next call to `fscanf()` will consume it though.  So this format could become `"%d%*[^\n]"` and perform the same.